# Cython compile error "is not a valid module name"

Tags: python, compilation, cython

I trying to compile on windows a Cython file (.pyx), a file which I just saved from .py. Here is my project dir path.

```
c:\..\Project\App\Analyzer\
_init_.py
Few_other_files.py
consolidated_loop_C.pyx
cl_setup.py
```

Here is my cl_setup.py

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension


setup(
    name = "Consolidated Loop",
    ext_modules = cythonize("consolidated_loop_C.pyx")
)
```

I am using below statement for compling in the same folder.

```
python cl_setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But I am getting the below error. my guess is I am missing certain parameters to cythonize(), tried to research without any luck.

[image]

Comment: It's picking up a dash from your path and complaining about it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799506/something-wrong-when-i-compile-cython-with-c for the same issue). I'm not really sure why exactly it's doing it. The simple solution is to rename the directory (but that isn't really a proper solution - you shouldn't have to do that).

Comment: @DavidW yes you were right it was the dash in the folder name. I have renamed the folder for now. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, change your setup.py file to only use distutils

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    name = "Consolidated Loop",
    ext_modules = cythonize("consolidated_loop_C.pyx")
)
```

This is to facilitate the debugging for potential repliers.

Then, from a few experiments and other SO posts [Python building cython extension with setup creates subfolder when __init__.py exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653047/python-building-cython-extension-with-setup-creates-subfolder-when-init-py-e) and [The command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` always create a new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847561/the-command-python-setup-py-build-ext-inplace-always-create-a-new-directory)

I suggest to either move your cython file in a subdirectory or remove the `__init__.py` file. The latter issue very probably causes Python or Cython to guess the name of the module of the current directory, hence the dash issue. Also, `setup.py` files cannot live in the directory of the module and that will cause trouble.

If you intend to distribute or package your code, the former option (moving cleanly the files in a subdirectory with its own `__init__.py`, etc) is preferable. Else, just remove `__init__.py` and be done. This will create, with `build_ext --inplace`, a locally available Python module `consolidated_loop_C.so`.

Answer (score 2):

hyphen '-' in your file name might cause this error. To solve this error, I renamed `-` to `_`.

Comment: Same issue in Linux (OpenSuse 15.2) with cython for Python 3.6.8... changed my filename to use underscores (which PyQt5 Designer shouts about) instead of hyphens, and cython worked. Frustrating. Thank you for providing the vital clue @user2058374.