# Error compiling Cython file:word2vec_inner.pyx:1:0: 'TWE-1.gensim.models.word2vec_inner' is not a valid modu le name

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
extensions = [
    Extension("word2vec_inner", ["word2vec_inner.pyx"],
          include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
    ]
setup(
    name="word2vec_inner",
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)
```

error:

```
Warning: Extension name 'word2vec_inner' does not match fully qualified name
'TWE-1.gensim.models.word2vec_inner' of 'word2vec_inner.pyx'
Compiling word2vec_inner.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing word2vec_inner.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
#!/usr/bin/env cython
^
------------------------------------------------------------

word2vec_inner.pyx:1:0: 'TWE-1.gensim.models.word2vec_inner' is not a valid 
module name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\PyCharm 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "D:\PyCharm 2017.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "D:/pycharm/TWE/TWE-1/gensim/models/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.27.3-py2.7-
win32.egg\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1039, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cython-0.27.3-py2.7-
win32.egg\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1161, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: word2vec_inner.pyx
```

I have install the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 and cython, but it can't compile. It always appears this problem. 
how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to solve from [Cython compile error "is not a valid module name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102656/cython-compile-error-is-not-a-valid-module-name)
 it was the dash in the folder name. I have renamed the folder for now. But I don't know why.